# Salt in PBKDF2 - Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, salt, pbkdf2

I'm just learning about securing password while developing using MySQL and Python, following [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/python-tutorials/securely-hash-passwords-in-python/).

It's my understanding that the userpassword is stored at the database hashed, and the salt is stored along side unencrypted, so that we can grab the hashed password and the salt, and rehash using the salt the inputted password, then compare the two.

Though, when using PBKDF2 (via the `passlib.hash.sha256_crypt()` function) I can't set my own salt, only its size. So how can I rehash the password using the same salt so I can compare both?

Comment: [`hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac) takes a salt. What function are you using?

Comment: Im using pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt, following the guide in http://www.cyberciti.biz/python-tutorials/securely-hash-passwords-in-python/

Comment: That [implementation](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html#passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha256) also takes a salt. When not specified, one is generated for you.

Comment: Can I just do pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(arg, arg, salt='blabla235') ?

Comment: Note that the returned string *contains the salt*, so you don't need to generate one up front. The string is of the form `$<type>$rounds=<rounds>$salt$hash`, so if you want to store the hash separately you can if you want to.

Comment: Yes, the documentation certainly states a `salt` argument is accepted. `pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt("password", rounds=200000, salt='blabla235')`

Comment: "TypeError: salt must be bytes, not str"

Comment: It would seem like salt is the same thing as salt_size

Comment: So pass in bytes: `b'blabla235'`. No, `salt_size` determines how big a salt is generated for you. It is **not** the same thing as `salt`.

Comment: that works, huh I guess simply converting was enough. Thanks a lot! Please reply with an answer so I can check it as right

Comment: Please edit your question first to make it clear what function and tutorial you were using. As it stands it doesn't meet our question requirements.

Comment: Okay, should I send you a message once its corrected?

Comment: That'd be helpful :-) I *may* not have time tonight but will do so then tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Passlib Password Hash interface](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.ifc.html) either lets you set the salt *size*, *or* the `salt` value itself. From the [documentation on `pbkdf2_sha256`](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html#passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha256):

> - `salt` (*bytes*) Optional salt bytes. If specified, the length must be between 0-1024 bytes. If not specified, a 16 byte salt will be autogenerated (this is recommended).
> - `salt_size` (*int*) – Optional number of bytes to use when autogenerating new salts. Defaults to 16 bytes, but can be any value between 0 and 1024.

so you *can* set your own pre-generated salt:

```
>>> from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
>>> pbkdf2_sha256.hash("password", rounds=200000, salt=b'spamhameggs')
'$pbkdf2-sha256$200000$c3BhbWhhbWVnZ3M$WL9OLVcb3f7HqHeNT./kCJeunydLCi4JykzEuAdewcI'
```

However, note that the salt is part of the returned string. The string contains not only the resulting hash, but also the algorithm, the number of rounds used *and* the salt used, delimited by `$`. The salt is [encoded with a modified form of base64](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.utils.binary.html#base64-encoding). You can verify this by decoding the string `c3BhbWhhbWVnZ3M` again::

```
>>> from passlib.utils.binary import ab64_decode
>>> ab64_decode(b'c3BhbWhhbWVnZ3M')
b'spamhameggs'
```

See the [*Format & Algorithm*](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html#format-algorithm) section for the `pbkdf2_sha256` docs.

So when you store the full string `pbkdf2_sha256` in the database, *everything to validate the string* is right there in the value, including the salt. Leaving generating a random salt is best left to that library as it'll use a secure method to generate one.

You may want to read the [Passlib tutorial on password hashing](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/narr/hash-tutorial.html), which includes coverage of how to hash passwords when storing in the database, and how to verify them again (e.g. using `pdkdf2_sha256.verify(password_user_entered, hash_stored_in_database)`), which covers exactly this ground.

Comment: How secure is passlib? Perhaps I'm a bid paranoid, but are there standard libraries that do that? Maintained by Python devs?

Comment: @Riya: it's a long-running, popular Open Source library to handle this task, and as far as I know, the defacto library for this in the Python ecosystem. I don't think you can get more 'standard' than this.

Comment: @Riya: searching on GitHub I found ~40k mentions in [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/search?q=passlib+filename%requirements.txt&type=code), [`setup.cfg`](https://github.com/search?q=passlib+filename%3Asetup.cfg&type=code), [`pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/search?q=passlib+filename%3Apyproject.toml&type=code) and [`Pipfile`](https://github.com/search?q=passlib+filename%3APipfile&type=code) dependency files.

Comment: @Riya: last but not least, it's the de-facto password hashing library for most Python web frameworks; e.g. the official FastAPI tutorial [references it](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/#install-passlib), and while Flask has several packages handling user logins, at least 3 of them use passlib for hashing (Flask[`-User`](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [`-Security`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) and [`-Security-Too`](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).